# Using ArcGIS Online for public participation?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-notes

We have an ArcGIS Online Organizational account setup with several maps facing the public.

I would like to create an application using one of our maps that has the added functionality of allowing the public (anyone, not just those with an ArcGIS Online account) to place a point/marker on the map and submit it with a comment.

The comments would need to be posted to a database (or emailed to me) with coordinates.

Has anyone developed such an application, or seen any templates available similar to this?

ArcGIS Online's Map Notes are close to what I'm looking for, but editing map notes is restricted to the author.

Comment: For those of you that are interested, I ended up using ArcGIS Online for this. The map service was hosted on our end pointing at our public SDE instance. The editable comment layer was hosted in ArcGIS Online.  The public was able to add a point and enter comments. After the comment period closed, I downloaded the comments as a geodatabase for further analysis. The application was built using the Web AppBuilder. Worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. If you want to enable editing, you could make an editable feature layer (or layers) and use the [Editor widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/editor-amd.html). This will allow people to create, edit and delete features.

However, writing the "wrapper" functionality to handle permissions (eg, only the creator of a feature can edit or delete it) and routing of comments into your separate database would be your responsibility, outside of the ArcGIS framework.

[Social Pinpoint](http://www.socialpinpoint.com.au/) is one application I'm aware of which does something similar, although this is based on Google Maps. This is an application that these developers have built themselves, I believe using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: Late to the table here but thanks for the mention Stephen. There are tools like we created, (Social Pinpoint) and others that work straight out of the box for this sort of thing